# I need suggestions for something alternative to apple subscription?

Tags: iphone, app-store

In my country apple does not support subscription, I can't make an app that can purchase monthly or period of time subscription, any alternatives?

Comment: I would write to Apple directly and ask for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Apple and ask if this is a temporary or constant condition. If it's temporary, wait it out.

Otherwise, you can implement login screens and authentication mechanisms as you would have them in a WebApp. The latest Developer Agreements allow for this (as opposed to the previous agreements where you **had** to offer inAppPurchase as well). The caveat is that according to the agreement, you may **not** link to your 3rd party payment/signup site from within the app.

Set up payment processing with the provider of your choice (e.g. PayPal) and manage your own database of registered users. Then, when a user starts the app, ask them to log-in by supplying a username and password. Send those to your server (e.g. using a regular POST request), verify them and deliver the contents to the user if he is authenticated.

Make sure to **keep the user logged in** after that to avoid annoyance.

The main challenge with this approach will be to let users find out about your service in the first place as you are not allowed to openly send them over in the first place. Then again, if Apple doesn't offer the functionality in your country, you may be able to get through review with it.

In either case, contact Apple, then act accordingly.